# Fisher r-to-z transformation: comparing correlation coefficient of multiple samples

Tags: correlation, regression-coefficients, fisher-transform

I am comparing the linearity of a regression model for two independent devices (n=10 each device group). The data is force (newtons) over time (seconds). The regression models show R^2 values of 0.9 to 0.95 for all devices. I want to do a statistical test to see if the **R^2 values are significantly different between the devices**. I came across the Fisher r-to-z transformation but this only allows comparing only **two** independent R^2 values, whereas I have **10 individual R^2 values for each device.** Is it possible to average the R^2 values (n=10) for each device group or is there another way to compare both device groups?

Comment: What do you mean by comparing linearity? And are you wanting to compare r-squared's or correlation coefficients? Fisher's r-to-z transformation is typically used when you want to average a bunch of correlations, I haven't seen it used to average R-squared values. But correlations can be averaged by r-to-z transforming the raw correlations, averaging the transformed values, and back-transforming the average.

Comment: I thought that R^2 and correlation coefficients are the same. I wanted to use the R^2 value from a linear regression, which I assumed was the correlation coefficient as well. That's a great suggestion - I could try transforming the R^2 values (or correlation coefficient) and averaging them before back-transforming it into an average R^2 value. Thanks!

Comment: No, they are not the same, but if you run a regression with a continuous dependent (y) and one continuous predictor (x), then the r-squared from that model is the same as Pearson correlation coefficient between x and y *squared*. If you have more than one predictor in the regression model, this link obviously breaks. I have only seen r-to-z used fro raw Pearson correlation coefficients, not for squared ones or for r-squared -values from regression.

Comment: (..."Pearson correlation coefficient between x and y *squared*..." above meant that the Pearson's *r* between x and y squared equals R^2 from the linear regression in this situation. Not that y is squared before the correlation is computed.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!